# Firefox sets wrong caret position contentEditable when insert img tag

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser, contenteditable

when i insert an image inside a `contenteditable` everything is normal with the browser like chrome, edge... However when I use firefox caret position is skewed .I don't know what's going on, please help me . Thank you in advance.
this is my simple code :

```css
.img-styl-cted {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-right: 2px;
}

.div-ctedab {
  padding:10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable class="div-ctedab">
<img src="https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/3/2023/03/goku-dragon-ball-guru-824x490-11b2006.jpg" class="img-styl-cted"><img src="https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/3/2023/03/goku-dragon-ball-guru-824x490-11b2006.jpg" class="img-styl-cted"><img src="https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/3/2023/03/goku-dragon-ball-guru-824x490-11b2006.jpg" class="img-styl-cted">
</div>
```

this is what shows in chrome, edge...

[image: display in chrome]

and firefox is skewed as follows :

[image: firefox display]

I don't have any solution until now and and I hope someone will share the solution to this problem

Comment: This is pretty weird because the cursor initially is shifted down, but as soon as you type text in Firefox it then corrects to look as you would expect. Because of this I kind of wonder if this is a Firefox bug because to me your code looks fine